# Standalone - \newlabel being written to .log instead of .aux

Tags: cross-referencing, debugging, standalone

In my compiled document, which consists of many sub-documents using `standalone`, I have *one* sub-document in which the Figure references are undefined - they show up as `??`.  No MWE I've tried can reproduce this error.

In case anyone wants to have a go at this particular bug, the `.log` and `.aux` files are here: https://gist.github.com/keflavich/5421912#file-thesis-log-L2696 (the link is specifically to the line with `\newlabel{fig:...}` in the `thesis.log` file).

The problem is that I am including multiple documents in a parent document, and everything goes fine until a certain document is included, after which `\newlabel` commands are sent to `thesis.log` instead of `thesis.aux`, which means that `??`s show up instead of figure numbers.

Comment: Did you read the `.log` file?

Comment: Yes.  I get "Reference `fig:...` undefined", but later there is a `\newlabel{fig:...}` entry, which I thought SHOULD mean that the figure label is included.

Comment: Oh... upon closer inspection, only the *failing* figures show up with `\newlabel{fig:}` in the log... the rest have that text in the `.aux` file.  What could cause that?

Comment: When a `\newlabel` command appears in the `.log` file rather than the `.aux` file, it means that the latter has already been closed or is not open when the `\label` command is scanned.

Comment: Thanks @egreg - any idea what could cause that?

Comment: So, I found one workaround to that problem - I removed the `\begin` and `\end` document from the document that was being `\import`ed.  I think this indicates a problem with standalone.  I'm going to revise this question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, this was a stupid problem.

`\include{preface.tex}` causes this issue.

`\input{preface.tex}` does not.

Sigh.